# Why is my MVC Action not model binding my collection?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my site I am gathering a list of numbers (for sorting) and sending them to my MVC action with the following code:

```
    $('#saveButton').click(function () {
        var configId = $('#ConfigId').val();
        var steps = new Array();
        $('#stepList li').each(function (index) {
            steps[index] = $(this).attr('stepId');
        });

        // Send the steps via ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: '" + Url.Action(MVC.GrmDeployment.EditStep.Reorder()) + @"',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { configId: configId, stepIds: steps },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    alert('Reorder was successful');
                }

                else {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Through chrome I see this sending the following data over the wire:

```
configId:1
stepIds%5B%5D:3
stepIds%5B%5D:2
```

In my controller I have the following method to receive the values

```
public virtual ActionResult Reorder(int configId, ICollection<int> stepIds) { }
```

The problem is that the `stepIds` collection is null.  Anyone see any reason why?

Comment: I've seen various resource say that it's possible to bind to an `IList<>` or `ICollection<>`, turns out I had to use a specific jquery option to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, jQuery changed the way it encodes arrays in the `ajax` method, so in order to continue being compatible with MVC, you have to set the `traditional` option to `true`:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action(MVC.GrmDeployment.EditStep.Reorder())',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true, // This is required for certain complex objects to work with MVC AJAX.
        data: { configId: configId, stepIds: steps },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert('Reorder was successful');
            }

            else {
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON.Stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html):

```
var viewModel = new Object();
viewModel.configId = $('#ConfigId').val();
viewModel.steps = new Array();

data: { JSON.Stringify(viewModel) },
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, it just complained that the `configId` parameter wasn't provided and is required

Answer (score 0):

I have had actions binding to arrays. I personally have an action with a string[] parameter.

Try

```
public virtual ActionResult Reorder(int configId, int[] stepIds) { }
```